# Efficiently refreshing TableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm reading data from my NoSQL Firebase database, parsing that data into individual components, then displaying them in my tableView. I've added table refreshing functionality so when a new piece of data is added the user can refresh and it will be added to the table.

The function that's call to refresh the table is the same function that does the initial table populating, so in a sense refreshing just restarts the view. The steps that are taken are:

1. Empty out array and dictionary that hold parsed data elements
2. Fetch data from database
3. Parse that data
4. Reload the table

Here's the full function:

```
func readEventsFromDb() {
    // 1. Empty out data structures
    eventsForDate.removeAll()
    allDates.removeAll()

    // 2. Fetch data
    let dbRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("pets").child(currentPet).child("events")
    dbRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
    // 3. Parse data elements
            for child in snapshots{
                if let data = child.value as? [String: Any] {
                    if let c = data["comment"] as? String, let p = data["user"] as? String, let t = data["type"] as? Int, let d = data["date"] as? UInt64 {
                        let event = PetEvent(comment: c, person: p, type: t, time: self.timeFromEpoch(time: Double(d)))
                        let eventDate = self.dateFromEpoch(time: Double(d))
                        if (self.eventsForDate[eventDate] != nil) {
                            self.eventsForDate[eventDate]!.append(event)
                        } else {
                            self.eventsForDate[eventDate] = [event]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
     // 4. Refresh table
            self.allDates = Array(self.eventsForDate.keys)
            self.feedTable.reloadData()
            self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
        }

    })
}
```

It doesn't make a lot of sense to me that refreshing the table would pretty much just restart the view, as this is the only thing in the view. Is this how table refreshing usually works or is there a more efficient way to do such a thing?

Comment: Which part of the process in particular are you concerned about?  `reloadData` does not restart the view - it recycles existing UITableViewCell objects (assuming your table data source is written correctly).

Comment: I was mainly concerned over the removeAll(), maybe there's a way to not empty out the data structures. Also reading every event from the database again is probably not smart, maybe there's a way to just fetch new ones. Lastly I was concerned about reloading the table but from what you said it's not as big of a deal as I imagined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ref.observe` instead of `ref.observeSingleEvent` to continuous updating the table view.

```
ref.observe(.childAdded ...) //insert row
ref.observe(.childRemoved ...) //remove row
ref.observe(.childChanged ...) //update row
```

Comment: Exactly the solution indeed: Firebase fires `.child...` events at precisely the granularity needed to efficiently update the view.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Hi! Sorry this is off topic, just wanted to let you know you're my favorite person on StackOverFlow. Thanks for always helping people out including an up and coming CS student such as myself.

Comment: Hey Peter, would you recommend doing this on the initial table populating by using `.insertRowsAtIndexPaths` or just for refreshing?

Comment: @MarksCode I'm using `.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, ... tableView.reloadData()..)` for initial table view data. And use `childAdded`, `childRemoved` and `childChanged` for updating tableView. (Some data are duplicated from `.value` and `. childAdded `, need append table data selectivity )

Comment: @PeterCheng `childAdded` gets every piece of data AFAIR, how are you making sure that you're not reinserting values that were already put in from the initial load?

Comment: @MarksCode Using `snapshot.key` as a Dictionary key , `if self.dict[snapshot.key] == nil {
                    self.dict[snapshot.key] = true
                    // append item
                    // insert row
                }`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you would do so much manual work to have the user refresh this data - one of the biggest values of Firebase is that you can do this automatically. This can work, but is definitely not how "most other applications" do this.

I would STRONGLY recommend you take a look at the FirebaseUI project:
https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS

This includes data sources for UITableView and UICollectionView displays that handle 90% of the work behind what you're doing, but also support incremental (and animated, like other iOS apps) row display. If a row is deleted, for instance, the user would see that deletion with a nice animation, while maintaining their scroll position within the table. (The solution you've outlined will lose this position, which isn't very user-friendly.)

Included in the project is a simple example app that uses the module to show a simple live table:
https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/tree/master/FirebaseDatabaseUITests

Comment: Great answer. FirebaseUI-iOS implements `.child...` listeners to efficiently update a `UITableView` or `UICollectionView`. Using these pre-built controllers can save a lot of time, although they may be too limited for more advanced use-cases.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that for advanced use-cases, FirebaseUI (on all platforms) includes a generic collection class, such as FUIArray in iOS. This handles all of the listeners and update events/delegate patterns for you, but without any display-oriented code such as tying it to a UITableView. I've had great luck using this, for example, in apps that need to do things like sliding pager/tab views.

Comment: That sounds pretty cool Chad. Do you have the code for such a sliding pager available somewhere? We get regular requests for how to do this.

Comment: Unfortunately we aren't able to open-source the code itself as a module (just time constraints, not any other objection) but we used https://github.com/guilhermearaujo/GUITabPagerViewController which is a very simple layer that simplifies UIPageViewController implementations. We simply used FUIArray and wired its delegate callbacks to appropriate GUITabPagerViewController methods. If I can, I'll try to work up a Gist. I doubt it's more than 200 lines of code...